# How does the equation $a^2 \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} - \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}=0$ change with the change of variables?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

How does the equation
$$a^2 \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} - \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}=0$$
change with the following change of variables:
$$
\begin{cases}
u = x + ay \\
v = x - ay
\end{cases}
$$
Write the form of the equation with the new variables.

---

I solved the system of changes with respect to $x$ and $y$ to get
$$
\begin{cases}
x = \cfrac{u + v}{2} \\
y = \cfrac{u - v}{2a}
\end{cases}
$$
Now, we have that $f(x,y) = f\bigg(\cfrac{u + v}{2}, \cfrac{u - v}{2a}\bigg)$. Then, we find partial derivatives with respect to both new variables:
$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial v} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{1}{2a}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \\[3pt]
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u^2} &= \frac{1}{4}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} + \bigg(\frac{1}{8a^2} 
 + \frac{1}{8a}\bigg)\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x ~\partial y} + \frac{1}{4a^2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
$$
Likewise, we get
$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial v^2} = \frac{1}{4}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} + \bigg(\frac{1}{8a^2} 
 - \frac{1}{8a}\bigg)\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x ~\partial y} + \frac{1}{4a^2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}$$
However, I don't know how to get rid of the mixed derivatives neither do I know if I have been doing everything right so far.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Strong hint**

How about if you write this:

$$
g(u, v) = f(\frac{u+v}{2}, \frac{u-v}{2a}),
$$
instead?

Now you're not using the name "f" for two different functions. You can then write
$$
g(x+ax, x-ay) = f(x, y),
$$
and discover that (using subscript numerals to indicate derivatives, so that $f_1$ means "derivative of $f$ with respect to its first argument")

\begin{align}
f_1(x, y) &= g_1(x+ ay, x-ay) \cdot 1 + g_2(x+ay, x-ay) \cdot 1\\
f_2(x, y) &= g_1(x+ ay, x-ay) \cdot a + g_2(x+ay, x-ay) \cdot (-a)
\end{align}
and then, differentiating each of these, a formula for $f_{11}$ and $f_{22}$, which you can substitute into your original equation, which told you that
$$
a^2 f_{11}(x, y) -f_{22}(x, y) = 0.
$$
That will give you an expression relating various derivatives of $g$ to zero.

Comment: Thank you. I was just trying to get it till the end... Could you just verify my answer: $$4a^2\frac{\partial^2 f}{du~dv} = a^2f_{11}-f_{22}$$

Comment: Nope -- I can't verify that; I've got other things I'm doing right now.

Comment: Ok, no problem. Thank you for your response.